# Android ListView in fragment example

Tags: android, listview, fragment

Where can I find an example of using `ListView` in `Fragment`? I know that there is an example in samples, but unfortunately I could not find it. Maybe you can suggest something?

Comment: A nice working example is described [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listfragments)

Answer (score 15):

Your Fragment can subclass [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html).
And onCreateView() from `ListFragment` will return a `ListView` you can then populate.